# Error when running apt upgrade: "libjpeg-turbo8 : Breaks ..."

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 20.04

How do I fix the problem ??

```
spyam@linux:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for spyam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg-turbo8 : Breaks: libjpeg-turbo8:i386 (!= 2.0.3-0ubuntu1) but 2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1 is installed
 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 : Breaks: libjpeg-turbo8 (!= 2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1) but 2.0.3-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
spyam@linux:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  glib-networking:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-x:i386
  i965-va-driver:i386 intel-media-va-driver:i386 libaa1:i386 libaom0:i386
  libaribb24-0:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386
  libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libatomic1:i386
  libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
  libavc1394-0:i386 libavutil56:i386 libbrotli1:i386 libbsd0:i386
  libcaca0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386
  libcapi20-3:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libcodec2-0.9:i386 libcups2:i386
  libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386
  libdv4:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386 libexpat1:i386
  libffi7:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386
  libfribidi0:i386 libgdbm-compat4:i386 libgdbm6:i386 libgl1:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
  libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libgmp10:i386
  libgnutls30:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386
  libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386
  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed5:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386
  libicu66:i386 libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libigdgmm11:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386
  libldap-2.4-2:i386 libllvm9:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmp3lame0:i386
  libmpg123-0:i386 libmysqlclient21:i386 libnettle7:i386 libnghttp2-14:i386
  libnuma1:i386 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386
  libopencore-amrnb0:i386 libopencore-amrwb0:i386 libopenjp2-7:i386
  libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386
  libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386
  libpcap0.8:i386 libpci3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libperl5.30:i386
  libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386 libproxy1v5:i386 libpsl5:i386
  libpulse0:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 librtmp1:i386
  libsamplerate0:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsensors5:i386 libshine3:i386
  libshout3:i386 libslang2:i386 libsnappy1v5:i386 libsndfile1:i386
  libsndio7.0:i386 libsnmp35:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386 libsoxr0:i386
  libspeex1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssh-4:i386 libstb0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
  libswresample3:i386 libtag1v5:i386 libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 libtasn1-6:i386
  libthai0:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtwolame0:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386
  libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386 libvdpau1:i386
  libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvkd3d1:i386 libvo-amrwbenc0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386
  libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx6:i386 libvulkan1:i386 libwavpack1:i386
  libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386
  libwebp6:i386 libwebpmux3:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-155:i386 libx265-179:i386
  libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
  libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386
  libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
  libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386
  libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386
  libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386
  libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzvbi0:i386
  mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libjpeg-turbo8
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libjpeg-turbo8
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/117 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 228438 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg-turbo8_2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 (2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1) over (2.0.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-turbo8_2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libjpeg-turbo8/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libjpeg-tu
rbo8:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-turbo8_2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
spyam@linux:~$
```

Comment: I had a similar issue too. I solved this problem by the method linked below.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290836/how-do-i-update-ubuntu-when-package-system-is-broken

Answer (score 2):

Friends, I found the problem myself:

I canceled during the installation of `libjpeg-turbo8` (`libjpeg-turbo8_2.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`)

Now I have reinstalled the file and my problem was solved!